# Does Armor from different sources stack on your mechs?

Tags: into-the-breach

Armor is a status affect that reduces (most) incoming damage by 1.

There are several sources from which a mech can gain Armor:

- Natural Armor special, intrinsic on Hook Mech and Judo Mech,
- Abe Isamu's special (Armored),
- Psionic Receiver passive (*Mechs use bonuses from Vek Psion.*) when Shell Psion is on the board.

When a mech is affected by several of these sources at the same time, does damage reduction stack?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, multiple sources of armor will still only provide one armor to a mech.

Comment: Well, there goes my plan of putting Abe Isamu into Hook Mech with Ramming Engines, and laughing maniacally at my... completely inefficient ramming tank that's just an inferior version of Combat Mech. Huh.